# Ajax onclick event to datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, datepicker

how to make datepicker automatically get value and show the result from php so I dont have to make a button to trigger it

html:
`<input class="form-control input-lg" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" placeholder="tahun/bulan/tanggal" type="text"/>
<input type="submit" value="Ok" id="cek_absensi" class="btn btn-info input-lg">`

javascript:

```
var pilih_tanggal = $("#datepicker").val();
if (pilih_tanggal == "" || pilih_tanggal == null)
{
    $(".absensi_hari_ini").show();
    $(".pilih_absensi").html("<h3 id='pesan_absensi'>//error message</h3>");
}
else
{
    $.post("absensi_lihat.php", {pilih_tanggal: pilih_tanggal})
    .done(function( data ) 
    {
        $(".pilih_absensi").html(data); //show result from php
    });
}
```

basically press the button and then show the result on class .pilih_absensi

Answer (score 0):

I abstracted your code a little to make it more reusable. The main bit you should focus on is binding the change event to the datepicker so you can call the functionality each time the datepicker changes, and you can `trigger` it on load to allow you to put values directly in it from php on page load.

```js
// save your local jQuery objects
var $pilih_tanggal = $("#datepicker")
var $absensi_hari_ini = $(".absensi_hari_ini")
var $pilih_absensi = $('.pilih_absensi')

var datepickerChange = function(e) {
  // truthy and falsey are good enough to check the value
  if (!$(this).val()) {
    $absensi_hari_ini.show();
    $pilih_absensi.html("<h3 id='pesan_absensi'>//error message</h3>");
  } else {
    // we have a value so make the ajax call
    $.post("absensi_lihat.php", {
      pilih_tanggal: $(this).val()
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      $pilih_absensi.html(data);
    });
  }
}

// bind the change function
$pilih_tanggal.on('change', datapickerChange)
// call the change function on load
$pilih_tanggal.trigger('change')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="form-control input-lg" 
  id="datepicker" 
  name="datepicker" 
  placeholder="tahun/bulan/tanggal" 
  type="text"/>
<input class="btn btn-info input-lg" 
  type="submit" 
  value="Ok" 
  id="cek_absensi">
<div class="pilih_absensi"></div>
```